# What are the IP numbers when connected to VPN

Tags: ip, vpn

I am under Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS.
When I am connected to ProtonVPN, I see this

```
$ dig +short myip.opendns.com @resolver1.opendns.com
45.87.214.117
$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    ...
2: enp0s25: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    ...
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    ...
6: ipv6leakintrf0: <BROADCAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    ...
7: proton0: <POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 100
    link/none 
    inet 10.18.0.15/16 brd 10.18.255.255 scope global noprefixroute proton0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 .../64 scope link stable-privacy 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

I understand 45.87.214.117 is the external IP.

**What is 10.18.0.15?**

**If I had an ssh server in my PC, what would the IP to connect to (from another PC under a different router) be?**

**When would I use each of the two IPs?**

Answer (score 3):

10.18.0.15 is the address on the virtual interface your VPN client has brought up on your system for communication between your system and the provider's server, and thence to the internet at large.

This address is *private* to the VPN link between you and your VPN provider; traffic sent over this link will be NAT'd to some publicly routable address on the remote end.

Comment: Maybe worth adding that it's the local *private* ip.

Comment: Please see edited OP.
When would I use each of the two IPs? Giving examples would probably help a lot.

Comment: Edits change the scope of the question.  Also, the new question is underspecified: ssh to your PC *from what other machine* ?  If you're talking about another device on your local/home network, the answer would be whatever local address is assigned to interface `wlp2s0`.

Comment: @user4556274 - I don't see the EDIT changes the scope. It simply tries focusing on specific examples that might illustrate the (possibly correct, I am not judging that - it is beyond my knowledge and that's why I am asking) conceptual description given.